# Using SASS @use rule inside React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass

When I utilize @use instead of @import inside a React project (initialised with create-react-app) it does not return anything to the compiled CSS but the plain, e.g, `"@use "libs/normalize"`, but @import works just fine.
My node-sass is version 4.13.1 and libsass 3.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Here it has mentioned that this feature is compatible with Dart Sass, LibSass and Ruby Sass https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use